# Django count matches query with contains

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to show in order (as a ranking), users who have more in common with the user logged in.
I have this code:

```
me = User.objects.get(pk=sesion)

keywords = me.likes
result = []
for keyword in keywords.split(','):
    result += list(User.objects.filter(likes__icontains=keyword).exclude(id=sesion))
```

But this code shows something like this:

```
Username A
Username B
Username A
Username B
Username B
Username C
```

I would like to be like this:

```
Username B
Username A
Username C
```

Because the user "B" has more things in common with "me".

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't really do this with a full text search... The only option you have is to reorder the list in python...

Comment: If you made a `Like` model and linked is as a M2M field from `User` this would be easier

Comment: "likes" are keywords, something like tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html) class:

```
>>> Counter(result).most_common()
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Or, use [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by) and let the database do the stuff:

```
User.objects.filter(likes__icontains=keyword)
            .exclude(id=sesion)
            .annotate(total_likes=Count('likes'))
            .order_by('total_likes')
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say for arguments sake that you don't have the possibility of making another model.

What you could do then is this:

```
keywords = [word.lower() for word in me.likes.split(',')]
result = User.objects.filter(likes__in=keywords)
                     .exclude(id=sesion)
                     .annotate(most_likes=Count('likes'))
                     .order_by('most_likes')
```

This would save the evaluation of the queryset in a `for` for each keyword you have.
You're evaluating the queryset when you're doing the `[]` around the `User.objects...`

Comment: Likes are "tags" and they are in one field something like this: "Food, Python, Develop, Other, Other, etc..."